Any drawbacks on using static Events over Events?
I was learning about events(Observer pattern) where you had an enemy that would scream causing the player, camera and sound to react to it. One problem I had with it was that if you wanted to add more enemies than the player, sound and camera would have to subscribe to every single enemy. So if we had 100 enemies than that would be 300 subscribers. So how do we solve that? We could make the event in the enemy static
public static event Action OnEnemyScream;
private void Scream()
{
    OnEnemyDied?.Invoke();
}

That would make the event belong to the class, not the instances of enemies. So when an enemy screams that would trigger the static event on the class which would call all the subscribers. But should the class really control all the enemies like that? Should each enemy control there own screaming?
Another way that might work is to make an Event Manager which handles different events related to the enemy. So the subscribers subscribe to that manager and the enemy calls different methods in the manager when it screams/die/lose health, etc... So we have the Event Manager:
public class EnemyEventManager : MonoBehaviour
{
public static EnemyEventManager Instance;


public event Action OnEnemyScream;

private void Awake()
{
    if (Instance == null)
    {
        Instance = this;
        DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject); 
    }
    else
    {
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}


public void HandleEnemyScream()
{
    OnEnemyScream?.Invoke();
}
}

and the enemy call on the HandleEnemyScream method when it screams. Which one is correct? I would probably use a static Event if its only one object you subscribe too. Like a player losing/Gaining/ health or dying. Then I would probably do "public static event Action OnGainingHealth, OnLosingHealth, OnDying;" and then have x subscribers subscribe to it. But what should you do when there is more than one of something?

The main pitfall I've seen developers run into with static events in Unity is that they don't get automatically cleaned up on scene changes, so you need to be extra diligent about unsubscribing. The same applies to events on DontDestroyOnLoad objects.
When you unload a scene, these events stick around, including references to any objects that were subscribed to them (which may have been destroyed during the scene change). The next time the event fires, it tries to invoke methods on these destroyed objects, leading to errors. This is entirely solvable though, as long as you're consistent about removing listeners that are no longer needed, in OnDisable, OnDestroy, or in some other location you've verified cannot be skipped over.
With that, either approach you've shown will give the correct results, so neither is necessarily "right". That becomes a judgement of coding style and maintainability.
The rest here is just my two cents on style:
The observer pattern is mainly designed for situations where you have a small collection of known publishers vs a large collection of unknown or variable subscribers. So using it signals to someone reading your code (like a team member, or you six months from now when you need to iterate on this system) that the problem space has this kind of shape.
But here it sounds like you have the opposite: your subscribers (player, camera, audio system) form a small set that is known and pretty constant (you probably don't have levels without a player/camera), but your set of publishers is large and potentially variable (say if you introduce different enemy types in different parts of your game).
In a case like this, I think it makes more sense for your screaming enemies to couple to your event manager, rather than your player/camera/etc. needing to couple to your screaming enemies by subscribing to a static event on that class. Imagine how that scales as you add not just screaming enemies, but also snoring enemies, sneezing enemies, etc. Every time you add a new enemy type with an event, you'd end up changing the player class to subscribe to that event.
In general, I try to avoid putting anything in a player character class that's specific to only one kind of content that may or may not be present in an area of the game. Having a manager these enemies report to, which can handle telling the player how to respond, keeps the dependencies better organized (to my way of thinking) and avoids a sprawling player class as you add more content that interacts with the player.
